# Translation from IFC to SVF way too slow

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I tried to translate a big IFC file (150mb) for the veiwer and it took around 15 minutes only the translation without the uploading part. So is such translation time normal and can it be done something about it? I am currently using the free credits only for testing. Is there a performance increase with the paid credits?

The `/modelderivative/v2/regions/eu/designdata/job` is used with the `advanced` `conversionMethod:modern`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no performance difference between trial and paid accounts. Forge dev account with a valid trial plan can use full Forge features as paid one as I know.

**What happened after submitting a translation job?**

After submitting a translation request and it returns success, it means that your translation request is sent to our service and has been put into the translation queue successfully. It doesn't mean that your model will be processed by our service immediately.

Instead, you have to line up! Since our service resources are limited and shared worldwide, you will need to wait for enqueued IFC translation jobs from other Forge users completed, and then our service will start to process yours. Therefore, waiting for 15mins is not slow from my perspective.